# Error 'Can't resolve' en Angular con implementacion de Reveal.js

Tags: angular

Estoy tratando de hacer una presentacion con Reveal.js implementado en Amgular, como primer paso instale reveal.js, despues instale @types/reveal.
En mi archivo angular.json tal como la documentacion importe de esta forma:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/reveal.js/dist/reveal.css",
          "node_modules/reveal.js/dist/theme/black.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/reveal.js/dist/reveal.js"
        ]
```

Y en un componente llamado slides, importe de esta forma: `import Reveal from 'reveal.js'`
Finalmente en un ngArterViewInit coloque la inializacion en esta

Mientras tanto en el app.component.html tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="reveal">
   <div class="slides">
      <section>Diapositiva 1</section>
      <section>Diapositiva 2</section>
   </div>
</div>
```

Eso lo hice para probar si funciona, pero da el siguiente error:

```
Error: Can't resolve 'node_modules/reveal.js/css/reveal.css' in 'D:\ServicioSocial\reveal'

× Failed to compile.
```

Segui las instruccines de la libreria pero no se que es el error y la verdad lo necesito. Ya tambien me meti a foros y de echo al inicio tuve un error pero se resolvia instalando en types